# jQuery, default callback for ajax requests before any request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have many `$.post`, `$.ajax` call, they all returns with a JSON array. I realized that sometimes I have to check status codes, e.g. check if user is dropped. Thats ok, but now I have to put this status-check for all occurrences. By accindent, cant I set a default callback somehow?

Comment: what about the `beforeSend` option? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: why the down vote, its a legitimiate question. @john smith, your best bet would be to wrap your post or ajax call inside a function, and handle everything there

Comment: You can wrap those function with yours, something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531722/jquery-plugin-invoke-callback-method-that-can-then-invoke-plugin-functions-base#15532578

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/ - This allows you to set up default callbacks.

Comment: You want to check status after ajax response right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use beforesend method of AJAX

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    // It will fired each just before each AJAX request
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
        url: '',
        beforeSend: function ()
        {
                 // Here your code it fired just before ajax request
        },
        data: {

        },
        success: function (data) {
        }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:-

[**`.ajaxSend()`**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/)

> Description: Attach a function to be executed before an Ajax request
>   is sent. This is an Ajax Event. Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery triggers the ajaxSend event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxSend() method are executed at this time.
>
> **.ajaxSend( handler )**
>
> Type: Function( Event event, jqXHR jqXHR,
>   PlainObject ajaxOptions ) The function to be invoked.

Usage:-

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function( event, jqxhr, settings ) {
   // This will be fired before all ajax requests
});
```

**NOTE**

If `$.ajax()` or `$.ajaxSetup()` is called with the `global` option set to `false`, the `.ajaxStart()` method will not fire.